# vaadin flow vaadin-split-layout component has no onclick event

Tags: vaadin14

i am working on migrating application from vaadin7 to vaadin flow. the split layout component no longer have the onclick event hook on the splitter . that will lose feature if the new API doesn't have the onclick event exposed. is there any way i can add click event on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can react to the splitter being moved by adding a [SplitterDragendListener](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.7.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/splitlayout/SplitLayout.html#addSplitterDragendListener-com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener-) to it.